# jquery push element down on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using [blocksit.js](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/) to get Dynamic Grid Layout in my web-app.

It works perfect. The problem comes when I have to dynamically hide and unhide a textbox on button click, the boxes below are not shifting down so the textbox is going under the box below. See the image below.

[image]

I have tried whole day, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not creating your div dynamically then you should, in your markup, place the textbox above your buttons :)

**What to do:**

Let's say this is your HTML:

```
--BUTTON--++--BUTTON--++--BUTTON--
--------------TEXTBOX-------------
```

Make it like this:

```
--------------TEXTBOX-------------
--BUTTON--++--BUTTON--++--BUTTON--
```

Comment: I am displaying and hiding the textbox when the user clicks the comment button

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia the textbox is present in your HTML?

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia Good, then in your HTML place that textbox code above your button code

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia So, what you wanted?

Comment: I want to push the boxes below my textbox downwards

Comment: Try giving your textbox some bottom padding or margins.